# Open-Ended Styling for Shared React Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm looking to find best practices for providing developers the ability to style elements that exist within my React shared component.

For instance, I have a drop down and I wanted the developers to be able to select a predefined theme that would enable then to select a highlight color, font size, font family for the list element that exists within my drop down component. I created enums for the each of the default themes and provided a way to allow devs to define the theme object and add css to the properties that sat behind that enum. I then injected the style into the functional component.

However, I quickly realized that if I didn't provide a way for the developer to lets say adjust a facet of an element outside of the scope of the theme interface such as the font weight, the developer would not be able to style it and i'd have to go in and add it in and test that it works with all the other style combinations which became tedious and a lot of overhead.

I was wondering if there is an implementation whereby I provide refs to the elements in the component and provide and open-ended `CSSProperties` style prop that would allow the dev to style to their hearts content? Is there a best practice to do this? Please provide a short example if possible?

One caveat is that frameworks such as Next JS will encode the css modules and make it difficult to allow the user to provide css that'll manipulate the component due to the css element encoding or appended id's. This is why I thought the *refs* approach might work.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you would be using :part . This allows styling through the shadow dom boundary of the parts of your component that you want.

See:

[mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part)

an explanation by the person who proposed this: [explainer](https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/)

and some other [documentation](https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/css-shadow-parts-1.md)